# Can't get value of select field in a form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-selectbox

I want to get the value of all elements in a form on submit button. I serialize the data in the form but for some reasons that I don't understand in the serialised data the value of selected option on select field is not included there.

Here's a [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/2615/#&togetherjs=8TmcxUnGxc)

My form looks like this:

```
<form id='foo'>
      <p>
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea id='message' name='message' rows='5'></textarea>
      </p>
      <br/>
      <p>
           <label>Name</label>
           <select id = "name">
             <option value = "1">one</option>
             <option value = "2">two</option>
             <option value = "3">three</option>
             <option value = "4">four</option>
           </select>
        </p><br/>
        <div id='success'></div>
        <button type='submit'>Send</button>
    </form>

    <p id="showdata">

    </p>
```

On submit of this form I some jquery code that handles it. It looks like this :

```
// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#foo").submit(function(event){

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $('#showdata').html(serializedData);

});
```

Can somebody help me to understand where is my problem! Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms work on the name, and not ID attribute. Give you select element a name value and it will work.

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem. I didn't notice that @John Mc

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to correct but you have a mistake.
Look at `select` , it has no attribute `name`. So, `$form.serialize()` will not work on this element.

This is fixed by add attribute name to select

```
<form id='foo'>
  <p>
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea id='message' name='message' rows='5'></textarea>
  </p>
  <br/>
  <p>
       <label>Name</label>
       <select name="test">
         <option value="1">one</option>
         <option value="2">two</option>
         <option value="3">three</option>
         <option value="4">four</option>
       </select>
    </p><br/>
    <div id='success'></div>
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>

<p id="showdata">

</p>
```

More information : [Form Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use **`$form.serialize()`** in select element you should add attribute name in there because **`$form.serialize()`** will get values from attribute name

**Update**

https://jsfiddle.net/drhe1L9u/

Add attribute **name** to select element

Comment: Just use copy and paste and debug my code you will see that it takes without it, but only select value is ignored